# Three.js TextGeometry Wordwrap - drag as group

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a panorama site and want to be able to add a text label that can be dragged to the right location. It is a spherical pano for what it is worth :) The next 4 paragraphs are good info in general, especially if you are stuck like I was, but the real question starts below the +++

I originally tried using the regular canvas trick, but the canvas was too large vertically. For instance if I wanted to say "Hello World" that might be 120px wide and 15px tall, but the "transparent" canvas would be 150px tall, which would overlap other text objects, but not the panorama.

The other issue was if I wanted it to be more than a single line, so for instance if I wanted to say "Did you see this cool stream?" that could be broken up into 2-3 lines. After playing with it I got wordwrapping to work on both the canvas and the sprites, but ultimately the canvas problem killed it for me.

After that I tried Sprites, which was better about not overlapping visually the other text objects, but the canvas size was still too large which created issues in the onMouseOver intersects where if it was too close together you were likely to start dragging the wrong one around, or if you just wanted to pan / tilt the camera around to look at the panorama you may inadvertently click on the oversized canvas.

I tried multiple times to get the TextGeometry working, but always got this error "THREE.TextGeometry: font parameter is not an instance of THREE.Font." till I finally found out the API changed in the latest version which made all the examples on the web useless. After I found out about the API change, I was able to get it working, here is a fiddle for anyone that needs it: https://jsfiddle.net/287rumst/1/

++++++++++

In my app, this previous example using TextGeometry works out just fine, but only when it is a single line. When I loop through and do the next line, it becomes an extra object that you drag around individually, which becomes a problem when I want to be able to click on it to edit the text, size, color and so on.

I am not sure what to do about the issue of dragging all lines as a group. I expected it to work when I added the group to the `objects` array, which is how I did it before with the lines, but it doesn't work, so I was thinking it would be great if it could be wrapped in a transparent box with the faces pressed against the side and then use the transparent box as the handle for dragging.

Here is the example of it working with wordwrap: https://jsfiddle.net/ajhalls/73dhu192/

Outstanding issues would be dragging the group, and causing it to face the camera from the center of the group, rather than the corner when being dragged. `group.geometry.center()` I would have thought would work, like it does when it is a single line, but again it has issues.